# What does a Kafka partition look like?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and I'm trying to understand partitions. The general explanations online have not helped so I want to build a simple example to understand.

Lets say we have:

- 2 topics

  - Colours with 2 partitions
  - Numbers with 2 partitions
- 1 broker
- No replication

In this case, is the diagram below how the data will look? Here the data is input to partitions round robin, both partitions take some of the data from both topics. If this is accurate, how do consumers get each next value? They would need to move from partition to partition, but they could find data from a different topic.

(diagram below is inaccurate!)
[image]

UPDATE: Based on comments I think this is more accurate: 
[image]

Comment: partitions are per topic - you seem to have mixed them up?

Answer (score 1):

Topics are divided into partitions, where each partition will only have data for a *single topic*.

From "Kafka: The Definitive Guide":

> Topics are additionally broken down into a number of partitions

So your diagram should show two topics with a partition each.

Obviously the data from multiple topics ends up being mixed *on disk* (good explanation [here](https://thehoard.blog/how-kafkas-storage-internals-work-3a29b02e026)).

Comment: The partition number should start at 0 within each topic

Comment: "Obviously the data from multiple topics ends up being mixed on disk" I suppose it's not true. Partition is part of topic. On disk you could see hierarchy topic/partition/[segments in .log and .index files]. So partitions from different topics are **not** mixed up.

Comment: @ADS earlier revisions of the question showed messages from different topics being allocated within the same partition. I was pointing out the grain of truth, that this mixing does occur in terms of the segments being written (the segments are mixed on disk).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this detailed explanation.](https://hackernoon.com/thorough-introduction-to-apache-kafka-6fbf2989bbc1) It has some really good diagrams that show entire architecture from zookeeper to broker structure.

For log compaction and other low level design stuff, please go through [these](http://cloudurable.com/blog/page/2/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hope these images help you to understand. Sometimes images are better than words.

[image]
[image]
[image]